# "I better" as an answer

Tags: meaning

Is it okay to use "I better" simple as that as an answer.

Example if I wear a costume and someone says "you look like a mermaid" .."I better!"

Comment: It's probably a contraction of "I had better!", as in "I had better look like a mermaid, I put a lot of effort into this costume".